# In R, how can you test for selection bias when Heckman 2-step model won't work?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about how to correct for selection bias in an experience using R. In this experience, we evaluate the impact of slight tweaks in phrasing on web surveys participation. For example, if you tell people that most people participate, are they more inclined to participate themselves? This is at the end of a phone survey, where the interviewer asks the interviewee whether he wants to participate to web surveys in the future. We test several phrasings that the interviewer will then read out loud to the interviewee.

I have two dependent variables that I evaluated: the first one is whether the person says yes or no. The second one is whether the person actually participates to the survey, which will take place 3 or 4 days later. What I did at first is simply two logit: I first evaluate the probability of saying “yes” based on the treatment, and a few other sociodemographic variables (age, gender, income, the usual). Then I evaluate the probability of accepting, using the exact same explanatory variables.

But I’ve been told by my thesis director (this research is part of my PhD in economics) that this was wrong because it failed to account for selection bias. The idea was that, since people have to say “yes” to the interviewer before they can participate (otherwise they won’t be on the mailing list), the second model (participation) will heavily be influenced by what make people say “yes”, and not what makes them actually participate.

In that, it’s a bit similar to the famous Heckman example, where he tries to evaluate what determines wages but he only has data on people who work, who may be significantly different from people who don’t. So naturally, my director advised me to look into the Heckman two-step model. Except there are two problems: it seems to only really work if the second model has a continuous dependent variable, where mine is binary (they either participate or they don’t). And, perhaps more importantly, I assume that it is the exact same variables that influence both participation and saying “yes”. This is really a core part of the research hypothesis and I can’t really change it. But I’ve seen that for the Heckman correction to actually mean something, the two models have to be different from one another.

In the end, I really don’t know what to do. I’m quite bad at econometrics and statistics, and I feel a bit out of my depth here, so if someone could take the time to tell me what they think of this situation, I would be very grateful.

Do I really need to test for a selection bias, or is it acceptable to ignore it in my situation? And if I have to test for one, what method could I use given that both my models have a binary dependent variable and exactly the same explanatory variables? How can I do it in R?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you mean to post this on CrossValidated?

Comment: +1 to @AkselA's comment. Except for the "how do I do it in R" part, it seems to be very much more a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) than a SO question.  My advice would be to delete this question for now and post a 99% similar one (except for "how can I do it in R?") on CV. (You could ask for that on CV, but as a tangential comment.) Someone *might* give specifically R-focused advice, but even if they don't they'll probably give enough information that you can search for a solution yourself (e.g. try the `sos` package with `findFn()` to search CRAN packages) ...

Comment: ... if not (i.e. if you get a good general answer on CV but are still struggling to implement it in R), then come back and ask a new question. (But please *don't* simply post "is there a package to do X?" - that would be off-topic too.  When you post your new question, you should show evidence of research/effort [e.g. "I found package XXX, I tried YYY, it's still not working] and hopefully a [mcve] ...)

Comment: Finally, this may get migrated to CV automatically (if enough people vote to close & migrate). If that happens before you can delete/repost, you should probably edit the question to minimize the R-/programming-specific aspect.

Comment: PS can you get help or advice/pointers from your thesis director? It's too bad you're bad at econometrics and statistics, as this could be a very important aspect of this problem ... maybe you can get better ...

Comment: Well actually I already posted this on CrossValidated before, but it was completely ignored (it only had like 2 views), so I thought I might get a better chance by tweaking it and posting it here.

But I understand why it can be off-topic and why it would need to be migrated. I'll probably look for some other places, like the statistics subreddit.

And my thesis director doesn't seem that much better than me at technical issues like that unfortunately. But worse case scenario I'll just admit in the discussion it's a problem and leave it at that.

But thanks for the answers anyway !